# Какова структура папок настоящего “боевого” maven веб проекта?

Tags: java, сервер, maven, веб-сервер

Какова структура папок настоящего “боевого” maven веб проекта? Как она грамотно выглядит?

Желательно с примерами.

Comment: что значит `настоящего “боевого”`? Что значит `грамотно выглядит`? Что вам помешало самому поискать хотя бы на гитхабе?

Comment: найти нашёл. было бы интересно услышать разбор детальный

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Структура простых мавен проектов выглядит следующим образом:

```
project
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   `-- java
    |       `-- $package
    |           `-- App.java

    `-- test
        `-- java
            `-- $package
                `-- AppTest.java
```

В зависимости от типа проекта(web приложение, ejb приложение ... ) структура может отличаться.
Шаблоны можно посмотреть по [ссылке](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/index.html)